# Brute forcing/hacking Secure passphrases - difficulty for random strings vs real words

Tags: random-number-generator, passwords, randomness, password-hashing

I was wondering about this topic of brute forcing passwords,or ANY other way to deriving them - and asking myself whats more secure (relatively):

A Password which includes

A)  30 digits length- a entirely random string consisting only letters

B)  30 digits length- with 5 real words of length of 5

I am interested in the claim that for passwords, people should not use words that are in dictionaries and that it is better to use randomly generated strings. Because real words could be brute forced "dictionary attack" for example.

But Then I realized that it is actually the contrary taking place in the market: for example if you look at all those "mnemonic seeds" of crypto wallets, they include always many words which are real life words included in dictionaries.

So my question is  : What am I missing here technically, why are those dictionary-derived passphrases not susceptible to brute force/dictionary attacks, even though they are using real words?  And why might this be more secure compared to random strings of same length?

Thank you all!

Comment: This question and similar ones are asked many times in [securitySE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/204450/which-password-policy-is-more-secure-one-password-of-length-9-vs-two-passwords). Hint: ask yourself; how many words one has with 5 letters and how many you can generate random one?

Comment: Look up entropy estimation. Given an adversary that knows the pattern you use but not the specific randomly chosen password, likelihood of guessing correctly is 1/(symbol set)^(length). Symbol set can either be your word list or characters, and length is number of words or number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Passwords that contain dictionary words are certainly **not** as secure as randomized strings with the same length. According to the Oxford dictionary:

> The Second Edition of the 20-volume Oxford English Dictionary, published in 1989, contains full entries for 171,476 words in current use

However, English as spoken has around 30,000 if I remember correctly, and simplified English only 10,000. Lets assume 50,000 words are used (our alphabet), presuming that these words are chosen randomly. Then a fast calculation shows that we have about 15 bits per word (as $\log_2(50,000) \approx 15$). So we would need about 4 words for a 60 bit password, with 5 words we would have a very hard to crask 75 bits of "entropy". Unfortunately, this is a very big *if* as the words being not be chosen randomly if they are chosen by a human. Furthermore, the number of words will be very much diminished if they have to accumulate to (precisely) 30 characters.

Now let's assume we can chose 30 fully random letters. Again, humans are quite incapable of doing this, you would need a computer or other tool such as a fairly balanced dice to choose for you. But OK, then you'd have 52 characters at your disposal. The same calculations leads us to see that there are now $log_2(52) \approx 5,7$, so $30  \cdot 5,7 \approx 170$ bits of entropy.  That's a lot more than 60 to 70 bits (assuming that we can put about 4/5 words in 30 characters, including spaces to separate them), and the 60-75 bit estimate is probably pretty high as well.

So where did you go wrong? Well, people are quite incapable of remembering 30 random characters. And if you look at the XKCD commic, we'll see that the comparison is much more about 8 random characters (say, 6 bits per character if we include a few special ones) and a password of around 4 words. The idea is that the latter is much easier to be remberred. With a 8 character password, people are going to forget *unless* the password is not really random, in which case security if of course decreased *significantly*.

[image]

That said, if you use a random password generator / password storage anyway, then you don't need such tricks. Just use randomized characters. And maybe one of the passwords consisting of random words to unlock them.

Comment: *"Again, humans are quite incapable of doing this, you would need a computer to choose for you."* Incapable of **thinking** of random numbers, actually. Coin flips and dice are other tools humans can use that don't require a computer. (Although I recommend being cautious using either dice or coins since they will have bias. A huge bias compared to small probabilities in cryptography, but not nearly as bad as with brain-generated numbers. (Also D20 are preferable. D6 are dangerously cheap. Card shuffling is bad. Von Neumann's method helps with coins.))

Comment: You can buy "casino grade", ballanced dice. They are slightly more costly, but yeah.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes  great reply thx!! so, just to be clear that i understood correctly:  does this conclusion make sense?

"it is not about that passwords including real words are more secure than random passwords,  it is more about the fact that passwords including real words are better memorable, than passwords with random strings."

Comment: Yes, I think that is correct. The XKCD comic of course skips this step by showing a "random" password, `Tr0ub4dor&3`, that is not random at all. Because of this the entropy is only ~28 bits. But a full random password as you describe has an entropy that is easily over 128 bits, commonly considered impossible to guess (in most situations, such as password hashing / password based key derivation).

Comment: hi @MaartenBodewes , please answer one quick followup:

What is more "secure" from dictionary attacks (or any kind of hack):  your above mentioned example of a couple words next to each other, separated by SPACES.  or the same words NOT separated by spaces?

I just want to understand if one should use spaces or not...  i mean, this sentence for example:

"Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point"

what would be your view on its security if I wrote it like this:

"Commentsareusedtoaskforclarificationortopoint" ?

thank you for clarification